# Best way to display a group/selection of radiobuttons from the choice of a single radiobutton?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form which for some questions would ask if something was included and if it isn't to supply a reason.

So I need a radio button which records to the database it's value like normal which I have setup with a RadioButtonFor and if "No"(false) is selected then a group/list of other radiobuttons will display.

Ofc this is just the ideal solution if this method isn't feasible then another solution would be to maybe a if statement in the controller so that if that main radiobutton has a value of "Yes"(true) then it would set the values of  x, y and z radiobuttons to "No"(false) when it records the form to the database.

These are the 2 ideas I have on how to get the same end result but for the 1st idea I think the easiest way to perform it's function would be in jquery which I'm fairly new at so would struggle to come up with how to do it

For the 2nd idea it's 1 not ideal and 2 I'm not sure how I would then reference those radiobuttons/code the if statement to do said task.

Any other ideas would also be welcome but hopefully with help on how to implement them.

Comment: I really could not understand because you almost haven't used any punctuation whatsoever it would be better if you could fix it see what I mean.

Comment: @rsenna all I could do was space it out a bit more so I hope this is better

Comment: @rsenna: so any ideas or solutions?

Comment: over 100 views yet only 2 votes all of which being mine guess everybody else was looking for something else when they stumbled onto this page.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Well I figured out the simpliest way to get the controller to sort out the validation which was 
`if (wd.AppTher == true) 
  { wd.AppTherRea = 0; }` this is the example for a drop down and for another radiobutton it would be instead of "0" or whatever value u want for the drop down for it to be "false" or if you want/have multiple options with int at the db field type then you just set your N/A or w/e value as the = too, for multiple RB or DDL then just add more in between { and }, wd was the value assigned to represent the table and otherwise a viewmodel value could be used.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with your first solution.  Render both groups of radio buttons on the page but hide the second group with css.  Then set some onclick events on the radio buttons in your first group to show/hide the second group depending on which one is clicked.

I think it is easier to just write the html for the radio buttons by hand because of the onclick handlers you are writing, but you could probably manage it using RadioButtonFor as well.

So your yes/no would look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="yesNo" id="yes" onlclick="$('#other-options').hide();' value='true' <%: Model.YesNo ? "checked='checked'" : "" %>/><label for='yes'>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="yesNo" id="no" onlclick="$('#other-options').show();' value='false'<%: !Model.YesNo ? "checked='checked'" : "" %>/><label for='no'>No</label>
```

Your other options would look like this:

```
<div id='otherOptions' <%: Model.YesNo ? "style='display: none;'" : "" %>>
    <input type="radio" name="XYesNo" id="xyes" value='true'/><label for='xyes'>X Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="XYesNo" id="xno" value='false'/><label for='xno'>X No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="YYesNo" id="yyes" value='true'/><label for='yyes'>Y Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="YYesNo" id="yno" value='false'/><label for='yno'>Y No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ZYesNo" id="zyes" value='true'/><label for='zyes'>Z Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ZYesNo" id="zno" value='false'/><label for='zno'>Z No</label>
</div>
```

In your action method ignore any x,y,z values if the first YesNo was true :

```
if(model.YesNo){
    //persist false values for x,y,z
} else {
    //check model for values of x,y,z
}
```

Comment: how would I group the radiobuttons then? and as I said I'm not that great with jquery so although I found (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159567/using-jquery-with-radiobuttons-to-hide-show-table-rows) this is for table rows and it doesn't look like it records original radiobutton value so still unclear on how to resolve this.

Comment: Just wrap your second group in a div and then show/hide the div.

Comment: how would I then set that div hidden and then have the jquery unhide it or have the jquery onload hide it if it's even the onload command and not another?

Comment: @Brian Any ideas on how to implement your solution then brian since I've managed to get rsenna's solution to half work with but sections being normally coded and then jquery to hide it but it doesn't want to allow me to show it again so either I need a new way to hide it with a complementing show code or a modified version of rsennas jquery code, I've tried multiple combinations and different ways to get that bit of jquery to work like replacing length with size and trying to make onclick events to show the sections but to no avail.

Comment: @Brian Well putting the onclick="$('#other-options').hide();" in <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.amwrAudit.AppTher, true, new { ...})%> and the opp for the other button now proper got it to display and hide so for most people that would be the simple solution out of this but now working on getting the controller aspect working with this.

Comment: @Brian well I tried fully implementing the Model.YesNo way of doing things but that wasn't working but instead producing lots of errors, is there any other solution which is more Controller orientated which would set the radiobuttons or even dropdownlists values as "0" or some other example?

Comment: @Brian Well I figured out the simpliest way to get the controller to sort out the validation which was [ if (wd.AppTher == true)  {   wd.AppTherRea = 0;  }] this is the example for a drop down and for another radiobutton it would be instead of "0" or whatever value u want for the drop down for it to be "false" or if you want/have multiple options with int at the db field type then you just set your N/A or w/e value as the = too, for multiple RB or DDL then just add more in between { and }, wd was the value assigned to represent the table and otherwise a viewmodel value could be used.

Comment: @Brian Oh yeh forgot to mention because I ran out of space in the other comment but if you add in about the controller if statements in your answer then I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @Brian Guessing your not interested in getting your answer marked as correct.

Comment: I did add in about the "controller statements".  That would be the part about what to put in the action method.  It isn't specific to your app because you didn't give any specifics about your app.  I'm interested in getting this marked as the answer, but not if you expect me to try and guess what your specific app looks like and write the code for you.  You asked for generalizations in your question so thats what you got in your answers.  If that isn't helpful for you, next time you should be more specific.

Comment: @Brian I never asked for specifics in regard to my code, I only used my code to show exactly how I resolved it and since you hadn't responded in 10 days and didn't cover the controller validation I made that the correct answer, so as I stated previously if you cover the controller validation in your answer then I'll mark it correct. Oh yes and if you could add in the RadiobuttonFor code solution too just so it covers all bases.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this may sound overkill, but I would go with *both* solutions. You need the javascript script side code to do it right from a presentation standpoint - and you need the server-side code to do the validation right too.

If you implement only the client-side validation, how the system will behave if a browser has no support to javascript, or if it is just disabled? You cannot take javascript support for granted...

OTOH, you would offer a best user experience if you added that client-side functionality you're talking about...

And about your doubt of how to do the server-side validation: that's easy with ASP.NET MVC - on load, just set the same ViewData entry/ViewModel property that you have read during post.

**Edit** So let's talk about a complete solution.

Again, I'm not sure I understood what you need here. You're talking about radiobuttons, but you also seem to think you'll be able to control them individually (many radios binding to many fields). That's not usually the case - a group of radiobuttons is normally bound to the *same* field, with each radiobutton meaning a different value (so exactly like a single dropdown list). Of course, that does **not** mean your database must behave in the same way...

See this example:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "Home")) { %>
    Select your favorite color:<br />
    <%= Html.RadioButton("favColor", "Blue", true, new { id = "rbColorBlue", class = "favColor" }) %> Blue <br />
    <%= Html.RadioButton("favColor", "Purple", false, new { id = "rbColorPurple", class = "favColor" })%> Purple <br />
    <%= Html.RadioButton("favColor", "Red", false, new { id = "rbColorRed", class = "favColor" })%> Red <br />
    <%= Html.RadioButton("favColor", "Orange", false, new { id = "rbColorOrange", class = "favColor" })%> Orange <br />
    <%= Html.RadioButton("favColor", "Yellow", false, new { id = "rbColorYellow", class = "favColor" })%> Yellow <br />
    <%= Html.RadioButton("favColor", "Brown", false, new { id = "rbColorBrown", class = "favColor" })%> Brown <br />
    <%= Html.RadioButton("favColor", "Green", false, new { id = "rbColorGreen", class = "favColor" })%> Green
    <%= Html.RadioButton("favColor", "Other", false, new { id = "rbColorOther", class = "favColor" })%> Other
    <div id="divOtherColorText" style="display: block">
         Describe the color you want here:<br />
         <%=Html.TextArea("otherColorText", new { id = "taOtherColor" }) %><br />
    </div>
<% } %>
```

This will bound to a single controller parameter, `favColor`, with a default value of "Blue". See that, for convenience, we're assigning a distinct client-side id for each radiobutton (`rbColorBlue`, `rbColorGreen` and so forth). That means that you'll be able to treat each radiobutton individually in your jQuery code, even if they represent a single value to the server-side controller.

Talking about the server-side code, that's how the action will look like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult HandleForm(string favColor, string otherColorText)
    {
        // Add action logic here
        // If you want to have a separated field for your database,
        // just do something like that:
        MyDbFacade.BlueColorField = (favColor == "Blue");
        MyDbFacade.GreenColorField = (favColor == "Green");
        ...

        return View();
    }

}
```

(Of course, you could also work with a ViewModel, but I'll not talk about that option here.)

Back to client-side. Let's suppose you don't want to show `taOtherColor`, unless the user selects the `rbColorOther` radiobutton. The jQuery code would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // If user selects any radiobutton:
    if ( $('#rbColorOther:checked').length > 0) {
        $("#divOtherColorText").show();
    } else {
        $("#divOtherColorText").hide();
    }
});
```

I guess that would be it. Let me know if I have missed something... :-)

Comment: I'm still not sure how to implement said features, I do know <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.BlahTable.BlahColumn, false, new { @onclick = "showReasons" })%>No    Then I'd have below it in <script> tags function showReasons() { and that's how I'd call it but how to get the the radiobuttons hidden in the 1st place and then to show them is what I'm unsure about since I'm new to jquery.

Comment: I've got it to hide everything correctly but it doesn't seem to like to show it again, I even set a [@onclick  = "showReason",] next to the id in the hopes   [function showReason() {
            // If user selects any radiobutton:
            if ($('#appTherNo:checked').length > 0) {
                $('#reasontest').show();
            } else {
                $('#reasontest').hide();
            }
        }]  would work but this doesn't want to trigger it either, unless do they have to be only "RadioButton" since mine have to be "RadioButtonFor"

Comment: Well I tested out a normal "RadioButton" and that hid it too but wouldn't show it again.